# Prove the summation identity

Tags: number-theory

> Let $m > 1$. Prove that $\displaystyle \left(2^{2^m-1}-\sum_{j=1}^m 2^{2^m-2^j}\right)^2 = 1+\sum_{i < j}2^{2^{m+1}+1-2^i-2^j}$

I see that $\displaystyle \left(\sum_{j=1}^m 2^{2^m-2^j}\right)^2$ becomes $\displaystyle \sum_{i,j}^m 2^{2^{m+1}-2^j-2^i}$ and that $(2^{2^m-1})^2 = 2^{2^{m+1}-2}$ and $-\displaystyle 2^{2^m}\sum_{j=1}^m 2^{2^m-2^j} = -\sum_{j=1}^m 2^{2^{m+1}-2^j}$ and so we have

$$2^{2^{m+1}-2}-\sum_{j=1}^m 2^{2^{m+1}-2^j}+\sum_{i,j}^m 2^{2^{m+1}-2^j-2^i},$$ but how do we use this to solve the question?

Comment: Are you sure that the statement is correct?

Comment: @RobertZ If this statement isn't correct, how would we get it to something similar to it?

Comment: Now the statement is correct and you can find a proof below.

Answer (score 1):

Just expand the square by using the identity
$$\left(\sum_{i=1}^m x_i\right)^2=\sum_{i=1}^m x_i^2+2\sum_{1\leq i<j\leq m} x_i\cdot x_j.$$
Hence, the square on the LHS of your identity becomes
$$\left(2^{2^m-1}-\sum_{j=1}^m 2^{2^m-2^j}\right)^2
\\=4^{2^m-1}+\sum_{j=1}^m 4^{2^m-2^j}-2\sum_{j=1}^m 2^{2^m-1+2^m-2^j}
+2\sum_{1\leq i<j\leq m}2^{2^{m+1}-2^i-2^j}
\\=4^{2^m-1}+\sum_{j=1}^m 4^{2^m-2^j}-\sum_{j=1}^m 4^{2^m-2^{j-1}}
+\sum_{1\leq i<j\leq m}2^{2^{m+1}+1-2^i-2^j}
\\=\sum_{j=0}^m 4^{2^m-2^j}-\sum_{j=0}^{m-1} 4^{2^m-2^{j}}
+\sum_{1\leq i<j\leq m}2^{2^{m+1}+1-2^i-2^j}
\\=1+\sum_{1\leq i<j\leq m}2^{2^{m+1}+1-2^i-2^j}$$
and we are done.